# Not all of your products are available in the requested quantity

Tags: magento2

When I am trying to ship an item I get the message **"Not all of your products are available in the requested quantity."**

The order comes through Magento 2 into Linnworks which allocated the stock and after a set time pushes a stock update to Magento. This means that in some cases the item on Magento is now below a minimum level, the item cannot be shipped due to this.

Is there a way to just bypass the error for just the ship section. Such as disabling the validation for backend shipping?

Comment: Can you ship even if there is no quantity ? If Yes, then try enabling backorder from configurations ?

Answer (score 0):

I followed this link and it seems to have fixed my issue:
https://www.mexbs.com/magento-blog/disabling-the-magento-msi/